# Why is my WordPress filter with AJAX not working with Arabic slugs in categories?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, filter, slug

i have code to filter products with ajax in wordpress but when create a category with Arabic slug filter doesnt work.it works correctly with English slugs.how can i fix this?

help to fix this for categories with Arabic slug..................................................................................................................................................

```
// Post Filter
( function( theme, $ ) {
    'use strict';

    theme = theme || {};

    $.extend( theme, {

        PostFilter: {

            cache: {
            },

            defaults: {
                elements: '.portfolio-filter'
            },

            initialize: function( $elements, post_type ) {
                this.$elements = ( $elements || $( this.defaults.elements ) );
                this.build( post_type );

                return this;
            },

            filterFn: function( e ) {
                if ( typeof e == 'undefined' || typeof e.data == 'undefined' || typeof e.data.elements == 'undefined' || !e.data.elements || !e.data.elements.length ) {
                    return;
                }
                var self = e.data.selfobj;

                if ( self.isLoading ) {
                    return false;
                }
                var $this = e.data.thisobj,
                    $elements = e.data.elements,
                    position = e.data.position,
                    post_type = e.data.post_type,
                    $parent = e.data.parent,
                    $posts_wrap = e.data.posts_wrap,
                    use_ajax = e.data.use_ajax,
                    page_path = e.data.page_path,
                    infinite_load = e.data.infinite_load,
                    load_more = e.data.load_more;
                e.preventDefault();
                if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
                    return;
                }

                self.isLoading = true;
                var selector = $( this ).attr( 'data-filterS' );
                if ( 'sidebar' == position ) {
                    $( '.sidebar-overlay' ).trigger( 'click' );
                }

                $this.find( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );

                if ( use_ajax ) {
                    var current_cat = '*' == selector ? '' : selector;

                    if ( !page_path ) {
                        page_path = $posts_wrap.data( 'page_path' );
                    }
                    if ( page_path ) {
                        $posts_wrap.data( 'page_path', page_path.replace( /&category=[^&]*&/, '&category=' + current_cat + '&' ) );
                    }

                    $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
                    self.load_posts( current_cat, infinite_load || load_more ? true : false, $parent, post_type, $posts_wrap, undefined, $( this ).children( 'a' ).attr( 'href' ) );
                } else if ( 'faq' == post_type ) {
                    $parent.find( '.faq' ).each( function() {
                        var $that = $( this ), easing = "easeInOutQuart", timeout = 300;
                        if ( selector == '*' ) {
                            if ( $that.css( 'display' ) == 'none' ) $that.stop( true ).slideDown( timeout, easing, function() {
                                $( this ).attr( 'style', '' ).show();
                            } );
                            selected++;
                        } else {
                            if ( $that.hasClass( selector ) ) {
                                if ( $that.css( 'display' ) == 'none' ) $that.stop( true ).slideDown( timeout, easing, function() {
                                    $( this ).attr( 'style', '' ).show();
                                } );
                                selected++;
                            } else {
                                if ( $that.css( 'display' ) != 'none' ) $that.stop( true ).slideUp( timeout, easing, function() {
                                    $( this ).attr( 'style', '' ).hide();
                                } );
                            }
                        }
                    } );

                    if ( !selected && $parent.find( '.faqs-infinite' ).length && typeof ( $.fn.infinitescroll ) != 'undefined' ) {
                        $parent.find( '.faqs-infinite' ).infinitescroll( 'retrieve' );
                    }
                } else if ( $parent.hasClass( 'portfolios-timeline' ) ) {
                    var selected = 0;
                    $parent.find( '.portfolio' ).each( function() {
                        var $that = $( this ), easing = "easeInOutQuart", timeout = 300;
                        if ( selector == '*' ) {
                            if ( $that.css( 'display' ) == 'none' ) $that.stop( true ).slideDown( timeout, easing, function() {
                                $( this ).attr( 'style', '' ).show();
                            } );
                            selected++;
                        } else {
                            if ( $that.hasClass( selector ) ) {
                                if ( $that.css( 'display' ) == 'none' ) $that.stop( true ).slideDown( timeout, easing, function() {
                                    $( this ).attr( 'style', '' ).show();
                                } );
                                selected++;
                            } else {
                                if ( $that.css( 'display' ) != 'none' ) $that.stop( true ).slideUp( timeout, easing, function() {
                                    $( this ).attr( 'style', '' ).hide();
                                } );
                            }
                        }
                    } );
                    if ( !selected && $parent.find( '.portfolios-infinite' ).length && typeof ( $.fn.infinitescroll ) != 'undefined' ) {
                        $parent.find( '.portfolios-infinite' ).infinitescroll( 'retrieve' );
                    }
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        theme.FilterZoom.initialize( $parent );
                    }, 400 );
                } else {
                    $parent.find( '.' + post_type + '-row' ).isotope( {
                        filter: selector == '*' ? selector : '.' + selector
                    } );
                }

                if ( !use_ajax ) {
                    $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
                    self.isLoading = false;
                }

                if ( position == 'sidebar' ) {
                    self.$elements.each( function() {
                        var $that = $( this );

                        if ( $that == $this && $that.data( 'position' ) != 'sidebar' ) return;
                        $that.find( 'li' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                        $that.find( 'li[data-filter="' + selector + '"]' ).addClass( 'active' );
                    } );
                }

                if ( !use_ajax ) {
                    window.location.hash = '#' + selector;
                }
                theme.refreshVCContent();
                return false;
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a classic issue with URL encoding. HTTP URLs can only send ASCII characters, and Arabic characters are not included in the ASCII set. Therefore, non-ASCII characters need to be percent-encoded before being sent, and then decoded at the destination.

One way to achieve this would be to encode the slug with JavaScript's encodeURIComponent() function, which is designed to encode special characters for safe use in a URL.

In the AJAX call where you pass the slug, you should encode it first:

```
var current_cat = '*' == selector ? '' : encodeURIComponent(selector);
```

Now, on the server-side, in the WordPress AJAX handler function, you would need to decode this URL-encoded slug before using it:

```
$slug = urldecode($_POST['slug']);
```

This should turn the percent-encoded string back into Arabic characters.

Please note that this is a only a proposal (the solution I've suggested), and you might need to adapt it to your specific case. Also, ensure that your database and your PHP file are correctly configured to handle UTF-8 characters. This means they should be set to use the `utf8mb4` character set.

Comment: Hi,
Thank You. where can i find $slug = urldecode($_POST['slug']); ?

Comment: $slug = urldecode($_POST['slug']); is part of the PHP code on the server-side that receives and handles the AJAX request. It would be located in your WordPress PHP files, specifically the file that handles the AJAX request for filtering the products.

The specific location of the AJAX handler function could vary based on how your WordPress site is set up, but it should be on the server-side and it's typically within a custom theme or plugin file.

Comment: If you're not sure where this is, you could start by looking in the functions.php file in your theme's directory. This is a common place for custom AJAX handling functions to be placed in WordPress themes. However, it could be located in a different file or even a plugin if your website setup is more complex or if you are using third-party plugins for AJAX functionality.